# Python Matrix overlap

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I have an problem with overlapping matrices

```
import numpy as np
import pprint

A = np.array([[1,0],[0,1]])
B = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]])

for i in range(0,2):
    for j in range(0,2):
        if i==0:
            if j<2:
                B[i,j]=A[i,j]
        elif i==2:
            if j==2:
                B[i,j]=A[i,j]
        else:
            B[i,j] = A[i,j] + A[i-1,j-1]

pprint.pprint(B)
```

and it returns array like this `([[1,0,0],[0,2,0],[0,0,0]])` but i want `([[1,0,0],[0,2,0],[0,0,1]])`

what is wrong with my code?

please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without any of the loops:

```
B[:2, :2] += A
B[1:3, 1:3] += A
print(B)
# array([[1, 0, 0],
#        [0, 2, 0],
#        [0, 0, 1]])
```

Comment: Thanks, hmm one more question. Then if i have 6x6 array and i want to make 9x9 then B[:5, :5] += A, B[3:8, 3:8] +=A this kind of code is right??

Comment: Depends on the overlapping region, but yes for example

Comment: Did this answer your question?